# How to find the device type and other information about device

Tags: android, device

I want to create an application which should only work on particular device type like 'Samsung'  or 'Micromax',So how can I find it in my code. Is it possible?

It would be useful for my application please suggest me the solution.  Thanks in advance

Comment: accept one correct answer else question is showing still unAnswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Build` class, ex:

```
public boolean isSamsung()
    {
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if (manufacturer.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains("samsung"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Build` Class for this purpose.

```
String BrandName = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURE;      // Manufacturer will come I think, Correct me if I am wrong :)  Brand name like Samsung or Mircomax

String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String SDKName = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
String DeviceName = android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
String DeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
String Productname = android.os.Build.PRODUCT          // Product
```

For More Info goto [this link.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER; //this one will work for you.
String product = Build.PRODUCT;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

let me know if any issue